# Plotting points on a map over time using matplotlib and geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame with a column that contains timestamps, a column ('coordinates') that contains coordinates (shapely points), and a column ('sentiment') that has either the value 'positive' or 'negative'.

Now, I managed to plot the points on a map. However, I want an animated/interactive plot that plots the points based on the timestamp.

So far, I have created a slider, but I don't know how to make it interactive and link it to the map plot. I know that I need a method that updates the plot, but I don't know how to apply that here. Can someone help me out?

```
sax = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])

start_time = matplotlib.dates.date2num(gdf.created_at.iloc[0])
end_time = matplotlib.dates.date2num(gdf.created_at.iloc[-1])
slide = Slider(sax, 'time', start_time, end_time, valinit=start_time)

base = usa.plot(color='black', edgecolor='white', linewidth=3, figsize=(80,45))
gdf.plot(ax=base, marker='o', color='red', markersize=100)

# Method that updates the plot

slide.on_changed(update)
```

See my answer to @DizietAsahi why this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: @DizietAsahi What I want is to plot a point based on a condition (once the time of the row is greater than the time on the slider, the point should be plotted). In the example you provided, the update function only operates on the x and y variables (coordinates).

Comment: At least the linked question and answer show you how to use a slider to update what the plot shows. Here you may want to show different points than in the example, but as it stands this question only shows `# Method that updates the plot` instead of an updating function, which makes it rather hard to understand where exactly the problem lies.